# Change string from sha256().digest() format to sha256().hexdigest() Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, digest, hashlib

I got a packet from a UDP socket. The last 64 bytes of the packet are an RSA-512 SHA-256 digital signature.
Using `struct.unpack()` I'm able to get it out into a string.

When I print the string, it looks like 'Output_1'

I want the string to look like 'Output_2'

```
from hashlib import sha256

h = sha256()
h.update("Some sample string here!")
print 'Output_1:', h.digest()
print 'Output_2:', h.hexdigest()
```

So, given the string that is the output of `h.digest()` can it be loaded into `hashlib.sha256()` and printed out like `h.hexdigest()` ?

Comment: "When I print the string, it looks like 'Output_1'. I want the string to look like 'Output_2'". I guess there's something missing there?

Comment: Do you know what format those 64 input bytes are supposed to be? You're also not showing your unpacking code.

Comment: The suggested duplicate asks about Python 3, but the marked answer (albeit a bit outdated for Python 3) works for Python 2 just fine.

Comment: I tried the encode/decode utf-8 but I get an error that some value is out of range (greater than 128). The hash has byte values greater than 128 in it

Comment: The answer you gave on using hexlify worked by removing the encode/decode methods from the end. I passed the raw data to hexlify and it worked as expected.

Comment: Whoops; I had overlooked the encode/decode bits. Technically, you could then put the final Python 2 solution as an answer to this question, since it's only half a duplicate of sorts. With a reference to the proposed duplicate answer.

Comment: NB: this has of course nothing to do with sha256 and the like; your question is essentially about how to convert bytes to a hexadecimal representation.